# WithStyles<typeof styles> in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

```
import { WithStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  root: { /* ... */ },
  paper: { /* ... */ },
  button: { /* ... */ },
});

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  foo: number;
  bar: boolean;
}
```

I am taking the above example directly from Material UI documentation. My question is, why does the documentation suggesting of using `WithStyles<typeof styles>` instead of `WithStyles<string>`. Could please someone explain in depth what the typeof styles evaluates to? In my understanding that would be a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I answer my own question here.

Provided we have the following in a typescript file

```
const styles = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

We can then declare another object that we expect to have the same property names as styles by using the following syntax

```
const stylesV2: typeof styles = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 24}
```

In this way, if a property is missing from stylesV2 that is present in styles, TypeScript will complain with property "x" is missing ..... but required.

Therefore in the case of `WithStyles<typeof styles>` we expect to cast a type with whatever is currently included in styles.